# How to reference a JSON Array using an API

Tags: java, api, openweathermap

I would to refer to the description field in the weather array using the getDescription function

```
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 600,
        "main": "Snow",
        "description": "light snow",
        "icon": "13d"
    }
],

public String getDescription() {
String description = String.valueOf(obj.getJSONArray("weather"));
String jObj = String.valueOf(obj.getJSONObject("description"));
return jObj;
```

How to write correctly getDescription functions to get the description value from the Weather array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the weather Array from obj, then retrieve the item you want from the array, then the description.

```
public String getDescription() {
    JsonArray weatherArray = obj.getJsonArray("weather");
    JsonObject weatherObject = weatherArray.getJsonObject(0);
    return weatherObject.getString("description");
}
```

This method is not validating anything for simplicity, but keep in mind and implement the appropriate checks for when any of those objects is null or if the weather array is empty.